# systemd-networkd, DHCPv6 lease - On debian 10 and above, unable to find org.freedesktop.network1.Manager in busctl output

Tags: debian, dhcp

I need to extract DHCPV6 lease information and from systemd-networkd's code it seems like DHCPV6 lease is not stored on disk, but is exported via DBUS using org.freedesktop.network1.Manager  node.
However, I do not find this node in my busctl output even if DHCPv6 client is running.

How do I get DHCPv6 lease info on debian host ? Am I missing something in configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

That's not a node you would see in busctl – it's the name of an interface (an API – a specific collection of function calls and properties) that the object supports.

What you see in `busctl` is only the list of services (a bit like a list of hostnames) that you're able to reach over the bus. All communication with a given service goes through the "service name" that it has, but that service generally exposes multiple "objects" (similar to URLs in HTTP).

Note that you also want the **system** bus with `busctl --system` – not the per-user "session" bus that it shows by default. Doing `busctl --system --acquired` should show the service name that systemd-networkd is reachable as, which is just **"org.freedesktop.network1"**. You can then ask it for a list of objects it has using `busctl tree [...]` (that is, `busctl --system tree org.freedesktop.network1`).

Once you've found the object you want, `busctl --system introspect <service> <object>` will request a list of all interfaces (and their methods and properties) that the object supports; that's where you would see the ".Manager" interface (on the "main" /org/freedesktop/network1 object, that is).

DHCP state is per-link; all that you'll find on the "main" object is indeed only methods related to the entire network manager service, such as the "GetLinkByName" function that'll give you the path of the object representing a specific interface (more reliably than grepping 'tree' or 'introspect' output).

```
$ busctl --system call org.freedesktop.network1 \
                       /org/freedesktop/network1 \
                       org.freedesktop.network1.Manager GetLinkByName s eno1

io 2 "/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32"

(result is an integer (link index) + object path)
```

```
$ busctl --system introspect org.freedesktop.network1 \
                             /org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32
```

I don't see any DHCP-related properties or methods there; I don't recall systemd-networkd ever having any in the first place. You *might* get something useful out of the Describe() method:

```
$ busctl --system --json=pretty call org.freedesktop.network1 \
                                     /org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 \
                                     org.freedesktop.network1.Link Describe \
  | jq -r .data[0] \
  | jq

(result is a string that contains JSON)
```

As far as I know, you actually need to ignore all of the above and go straight to the internal state files at `/run/systemd/netif`, where networkd stores lease information to be preserved across service restarts. (The files are named by interface index, which is shown in `ip link` as the number before each interface name. Note that `leases/` is the DHCPv4 lease directory, but I think the DHCPv6 leases are stored in the same way.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do not see v6 lease file in /run/systemd/netif and verified from systemd-networkd code that it does not save v6 lease file unlink v4 leases.  Also please find the source code where systemd-networkd is exporting lease info [source code link](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/829732d40a7b977e20f50c66ab25eb4d3900f425/src/network/networkd-dhcp6-bus.c#L53-L75)